# Excel: find instances in a column, where two identical nonblank cells are separated by contiguous nonblank cells

Tags: excel

In my data, each value occurs twice.  But sometimes the second occurrence is interrupted by one or more blank cells .  I want to test each first occurrence to see if only nonblank cells separate and its next (second) occurrence, e.g.

```
 value    occurrence   test 
    A      1          TRUE
    B      1          FALSE  
    C      1          TRUE
    C      2          (FALSE or N/A)
    D      1          FALSE
    A      2          (FALSE or N/A) 
                      #N/A
    B      2          (FALSE or N/A) 
    D      2          (FALSE or N/A)
```

'A' and 'C' are TRUE, but not B,or D, because only A and C recur without an intervening blank cell.   It's not really necessary to test the second occurrence, which is why I show the test returning 'FALSE' or "#N/A" (or blank).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compare the row of the next instance with the row of the space.  If the next instance row is lower it returns `TRUE`, If not it returns `FALSE` if there is no next instance it returns `#N/A`

```
=MATCH(A2,A3:$A$1000,0)<MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A3:$A$1000="",),0)
```

[image]